# yii2 controller JS

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

How to add JS inside controller. It says some error when I tried to do it. Here's my line:

```
    $script = <<< JS
$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{
    var \$form = $(this);
    $.post(
    \$form.attr('action'), //serialize the form
    \$form.serialize(),
    )
    .done(function(result){
       if (result == 1)
       {
        $(\$form).trigger('reset');
        $.pjax.reload({container: '#w0', timeout: false});
    } else {
        $('#message').html(result);
    }
}).fail(function()
{
    console.log('server error');
});
    return false;
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

How can I use javascript properly inside controller. Thank you.

Here's error:
[image]

Comment: What's the error? ;-)

Comment: seesm strange  ... normally the controller is main server  side  part of MVC ..and the js (client side) is normally added  in view  ..   explain better  ..

Comment: I'd updated my question

Comment: @scaisEdge yes it's strange. but it's the only way to achieve my project.

Comment: Error says controller does not have `registerJs()`, Only view have [registerJs()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail) function, .

Comment: @InsaneSkull is there any way to achieve it in controller?

Comment: Nope. You can write script in controller, i mean the code, that will run on client browser and you must register script in view.

Comment: You can definitely put your js in view where your want to trigger ajax request.

Comment: so you mean I need to store my script from controller in a variable. then register it in view?

Comment: Yes, but i suggest to write script in view only. According to MVC standards. You can write anywhere if you want. :)

Comment: okay2  i'll try it to store in a variable first. thank you

Comment: You could simply invoke a view  with a proper render  ad register the js in the view using  registerJs()

Comment: thanks. I'll try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add JS inside your controller by this way:

```
$this->view->registerJs($js);
```

Also, you can register js anywhere:

```
Yii::$app->controller->view->registerJs($js);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Single line answer is not very useful.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a brief explanation of what you think is causing the problem, how the problem works, and how your code segment corrects the problem.